# String Pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to improve my programming skill and i've tried the exercise in my text book. I would like to ask a questions here:

```
char strng[] = " Hooray for All of Us ";
char *messPt;

messPt = &strng[0];
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    cout << *(messPt + i) << " ";
cout << endl;

messPt = strng;
while(*messPt++!= '\0')
    cout << *messPt ;
cout << endl;
```

and this is the output :

```
  H o o r a y   f o r   A l l   o f   U 
Hooray for All of Us
```

My questions are :

1. actually at the end of the second output , there is a ? but it's in the reverse form. May anyone explain to me why this happen?
2. if i declare the char like this : char strng[] = "Hooray for All of Us";
   The second output become like this : ooray for All of Us

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're incrementing `messPt` in the `while()` conditional and only after you stream it into `cout`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are incrementing `messPt` when testing whether you've reached the end of the string in the while loop's condition:

```
 while(*messPt++ != '\0')    // tests *messPt = '\0' and also advances messPt by one
    cout << *messPt ;
```

You can refactor that to:

```
while(*messPt != '\0')
{
    cout << *messPt ;
    messPt++;
}
```

Or, if you are keen on being clever you can change it to this:

```
while(*messPt != 0)
    cout << *messPt++;
```

Sometimes the `++` operator can cause lots of hidden bugs. That's why some people argue it should be used sparingly.

Comment: Oh thanks :) .. actually the while (*messPtt++ != '\0) , is given by the text book. The exercise ask to modify the previous exercise (which is using a for loop) to the while loop .

Btw thanks for knowledge :) ... really appreciate it..

Comment: Oh one more thing : 
What is the different between 

   char *messPt;
   
   messPt = &strng[0];

and 

   messPt = strng;

I know that, for the first declaration, it means that the messPt is pointed to the address of the first array, but does it works same as the second declaration?

Comment: @user3040961, the declaration `char *messPt` and `char strng[]` are somewhat equivalent. They are two ways of looking at the same thing: an array (sequence) of chars. So `messPt = strng` is essentially setting the `messPt` pointer to the same memory location `strng` is pointing to (i.e. the start of the array). On the other hand `messPt = &string[0]` is basically a somewhat convoluted way of doing the same as the above but it goes about it indirectly: the ampersand takes the address of `strng[0]` which in turn, dereferences `strng`.